# A question about the definition of a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

[image: Definition]

While I was reading Do Carmo's differential geometry, I had several questions about the definition of acregular surface.

From condition 2, the author said   :
 "... $x^{-1}:V \cap S \rightarrow U$ which is continuous; that is, $x^{-1}$ is the restriction of a continuous map $F:W \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ defined on an open set $W$ containing $V \cap S$." I know that if $x^{-1}$ is the restriction of a continuous map $F:W \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, then $x^{-1}$ is continuous w.r.t. the subspace topology of $V \cap S$. "

However, how can we prove the converse? I.e. if we already know $x^{-1}$ is continuous, how can we show that it is an restriction of a continuous function $F$ which is defined on an open set $W \subset \mathbb{R}^3$?

My second question is concerned with the definition of "differentiable" of condition 1.
From [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularSurface.html), it requires $x$ is differentiable – does that 'differentiable' mean $x \in C^{\infty}$?

Comment: Your second question is clarified on the page! Read the sentence "This means that..."

Comment: i know i see it but i want to know if the meaning of differentiable in wolfram also mean infinitely differentiable.

Comment: @BenLi I'd say that the definition given on that Wolfram page is vague, and leave it at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the book, but based on this excerpt, it seems advisable to find a better book on differential geometry. It should not be hard to find something with a more modern perspective on the subject. The repeated references to the ambient space $\mathbb R^3$ are not really necessary.

Concerning your question, I think $W=V$ should work. Indeed, $x^{-1}$ is continuous on the set $V\cap S$, which is closed relative to $V$. (A subset of $V$ is closed in the induced topology if and only if it is the intersection of $V$ with a closed subset of $\mathbb R^3$.) In reasonable spaces such as $V$, every continuous function can be extended from a closed set to the entire space: for a precise statement, see the [Tietze extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem).

Comment: I don't think taking W=V as per user31373's answer will work, since we are dealing with open sets (not closed). I talked to my professor about this today, and we're fairly sure that to get the extension you can use the result that conditions 1 and 3 in the definition mean that you can locally write part of the surface as a graph of a function. Then the construction of W can follow, but this is cumbersome.

Overall, I'd say do Carmo's definition is not fantastic... Maybe have a look at some other books. But the restriction condition is often useful as a sufficient condition for condition 2.